# How to make an ImageButton clickable and hide the home logo Button in Actionbar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, clickable

I have added an ImageButton on the Actionbar. I have no idea how to make it clickable. Secondly, I want to hide the home logo button/image from the Actionbar. And finally I want to display a title on the Action Bar. Can anyone suggest me step by step what to do?
My codes are as below:

actionbars.xml

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:duplicateParentState="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"

android:src="@drawable/settings" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.blue));
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbars);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
  }
 public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
   ImageButton b=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.actionBarLogo);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    //@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Lists.class);
        startActivity(i);   
    }
});
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use a custom `View` in your `ActionBar`, you'll need to add it using a different method to make your `ImageView` clickable. Here's an example of doing that along with hiding the home affordance.

```
    // Initialize your custom layout
    final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbars, null);
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBarLogo);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Called when your View is clicked
        }
    });

    // Add the custom View to your ActionBar
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    // Remove the "up" affordance
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Your `ImageView` isn't a `MenuItem`, that's why your app force closes in `Activity.onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: Thank you, I was initializing a ImageButton instead of a ImageView. My mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

To set the title, simple add `setTitle(titleString);` to the onCreate method.

You already made the ImageButton clickable by adding `android:clickable="true"`
Now you need to get the button and add a click listener:

```
ImageButton iv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.resourceID);
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     // code
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please check my code.the button is not getting clicked.Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Place that in the onCreate method, you want the click listener to be there from the point where the activity is created, not just when a MenuItem is selected

Comment: Also if you're looking for that it should be ImageView not imageButton based on your xml